# web scraping function returns "undefined" but works when I use console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, callback

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request");


function GetPhysicalDmg(champname) {
        request("https://champion.gg/champion/" + champname, (error, response, html) => {
        let matchupData = {}
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var row = $('.footer-attr');
            var divvoorscript = row.prev().prev().html();
            eval(divvoorscript);
            var physicaldmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.physicalDmg);
            var magicdmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.magicDmg);
            var truedmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.trueDmg);
            return physicaldmg;
        }
    }); 
}
console.log(GetPhysicalDmg("Nautilus"))
```

The following logs "undefined" in the console. Apparently this is because request is an async function, and I've tried to use callback but can't wrap my head around how it works.

```
function GetPhysicalDmg(champname) {
        request("https://champion.gg/champion/" + champname, (error, response, html) => {
        let matchupData = {}
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var row = $('.footer-attr');
            var divvoorscript = row.prev().prev().html();
            eval(divvoorscript);
            var physicaldmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.physicalDmg);
            var magicdmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.magicDmg);
            var truedmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.trueDmg);
            console.log(physicaldmg);
        }
    }); 
}
```

this returns the value as it should.

Comment: Take a careful look at your code. You're calling `GetPhysicalDmg` function, but that doesn't return anything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: It does return something, look at my first example

Comment: No, it does't return anything at all. The return statement in the example is inside the callback function.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would do:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const getPhysicalDmg = async champname => {
  let request = await axios.get("https://champion.gg/champion/" + champname)
  let matchupData = {}
  var $ = cheerio.load(request.data);
  var row = $('.footer-attr');
  var divvoorscript = row.prev().prev().html();
  eval(divvoorscript);
  var physicaldmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.physicalDmg);
  var magicdmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.magicDmg);
  var truedmg = Number(matchupData.championData.dmgComposition.trueDmg);
  return physicaldmg;
}

;(async function(){
  console.log(await getPhysicalDmg("Nautilus"))
})()
```

Hopefully this way is less confusing, it is to me at least. Also that eval in the middle is a really bad idea in general.